# I get an error while creating a listview adapter

Tags: java, android

I would create some listview from my api json response, but I stuck with this LinkedTreeMap error in my code. Could anyone help me to solve this?

```
public class KategoriListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    Context context;
    ArrayList<Barang> barang;

    public KategoriListAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Barang> barang) {
        this.context = context;
        this.barang = barang;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return barang.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Barang getItem(int i) {
        return this.barang.get(i);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int i) {
        return i;
    }

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
    @Override
    public View getView(final int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
        if (view == null) {
            view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.custom_list_view_kategori, viewGroup, false);
        }

        TextView tvNama = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv_nama);
        TextView tvHarga = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv_harga);
        TextView tvUsername = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv_username);


        Object getrow = this.barang.get(i);
        LinkedTreeMap<Object, Object> rowmap = (LinkedTreeMap) getrow;
        String nama = rowmap.get("nama").toString();
        String harga = rowmap.get("harga").toString();
        String username = rowmap.get("username").toString();

        tvNama.setText(nama);
        tvHarga.setText(harga);
        tvUsername.setText(username);

        return view;
    }

}

public class Barang {

    @SerializedName("id")
    @Expose
    private Integer id;
    @SerializedName("username")
    @Expose
    private String username;
    @SerializedName("nama")
    @Expose
    private String nama;
    @SerializedName("harga")
    @Expose
    private String harga;
    @SerializedName("gambar")
    @Expose
    private String gambar;

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public String getNama() {
        return nama;
    }

    public void setNama(String nama) {
        this.nama = nama;
    }

    public String getHarga() {
        return harga;
    }

    public void setHarga(String harga) {
        this.harga = harga;
    }

    public String getGambar() {
        return gambar;
    }

    public void setGambar(String gambar) {
        this.gambar = gambar;
    }

}
```

The log result while I run the activity is

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.example.barangkoz.model.Barang cannot be 
cast to com.google.gson.internal.LinkedTreeMap
    at     com.example.barangkoz.activities.KategoriListAdapter.getView(KategoriListAdapter.java:57)`
```

Comment: Please add Barang Object class code

Comment: Use **Barang getrow = this.barang.get(i);** insteard of **Object getrow = this.barang.get(i);** then get all values from getrow (Barang) object

Comment: I'm a bit confused, why are you casting it to a Map, when you can just simply get the object and call the getters on it?

Comment: `barang.get(i)` is `Barang`, and if it  `Barang` does not extend `LinkedTreeMap<Object, Object>`, then you obviously can't cast it to `LinkedTreeMap<Object, Object>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing ArrayList of "Barang" Object in you adapter constructor it means you already have a list of object Barang in your adapter and you can directly use it without casting to TreeMap.

In your getView method of adapter change this

```
Object getrow = this.barang.get(i);
```

to

```
Barang barang = barang.get(i);
```

it will give the Barang object at the position of i from the list of Barang.
and you can get the data from this object using the getters methods defined inside your object Barang like this.

```
String harga = barang.getHarga();
String nama = barang.getNama();
String userName = barang.getUsername();
```

and set it to your TextView or

You can directly set the data to TextView from Barang object (without doing extra step to setting it in variable before setting to TextView), like this

```
tvHarga.setText(barang.getHarga());
tvNama.setText(barang.getNama());
tvUsername.setText(barang.getUsername());
```

Comment: Thanks, you didn't just give me the correct code but explained to me why my code is wrong. I'm so helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Replace

`Object getrow = this.barang.get(i);
 LinkedTreeMap<Object, Object> rowmap = (LinkedTreeMap) getrow;
 String nama = rowmap.get("nama").toString();
 String harga = rowmap.get("harga").toString();
 String username = rowmap.get("username").toString();`

With

`Barang getrow = this.barang.get(i);
 String nama = getrow.getName();
 String harga = getrow.getHarga();
 String username = getrow.getUsername();`

Comment: Thanks, Carnal. I'm so newbie on this

Comment: Yeah, I was lazy to just write the solution with your current flow, @Sandeep Insan explained it very well! +1 vote from me